# Copy DB from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have several databases on SQL Server 2008 that I wish to transfer to SQL Server 2012.

The two servers are on the same network but separate domains.

I am attempting a DB *Copy* from the one server to the new one and it connects successfully
I just am not allowed to select any of the DB instances to copy to the new server.

I have been attempting the connection from the 2012 end. I have DB sysadmin IDs at both
ends.

Any advice is appreciated.

Lou

Comment: I have sysadmin rights and I can see the option to select multiple databas on select databases page in the wizard. I guess you are doing some mistake. I would advise you to use backup restore mechanism to move database its very easy and reliable copy database wizard has problems as it is SSMS functionality.

Answer (score 4):

DB Copy has a number of limitations as describe at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664.aspx

This includes not supporting the copying of System databases, Databases marked for replication, or any database not in a normal status.

However, it does support moving logins, jobs, and so forth.

The typically best way to copy a database with the fewest issues is to do a BACKUP from the source server and a RESTORE on the target server.  This is mentioned here in the discussion of strategies for copying databases:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189624.aspx

If you also need to copy logins from the old to the new server, there are a couple of scripts documented at:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246133

SQL Agent Jobs can be scripted and recreated on the target server as well.

Comment: I have attempted to use backup/restore but for some weird reason I am only allowed to "verify" the backup and not actually perform the restore. Any ideas what may be causing this ?

Comment: Please update your question with any messages that you see from your efforts.  (Add them to the end of the post.)  One quick thing to check:  Are the drive letters and folder names the same on both servers?

Comment: @scopedial You shouldn't abandon the most straightforward method of copying a database because you're "not allowed." Tell us what restore statement you were using and what error message(s) you received, and we can solve *that* problem instead of assuming that RESTORE is not feasible (it most certainly is).

Comment: I agree, I suspected that it was a privileges issue that was currently beyond me. I was using the backup and restore helpers found in the drop down menus in the object explorer of SQL studio. Although the user IDs that I am using do have sysadmin.

Answer (score 1):

What I missed was that the 2008 server required patching. 
By applying the most recent patch bundle this problem has been resolved.